# How can I get the index of an element by finding the value of a property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Kinda tricky question. I have this set of panels and I would like to make a function that would allow me to find the position in the `array` of this elements. However, in this `array`, there are `subarrays`. In this case, I just want to get the `key` of the parent `array`.

Example:

```
[
   {
      "name":"apple"
   },
   {
      "name":"bone"
   },
   [
      {
         "name":"banana"
      },
      {
         "name":"tea"
      }
   ]
]
```

So, if I put `apple` in the function, it returns me `0`, if I wanted to find the element with the name `bone`, it would return me the index `1` and if I wanted to find the index of `banana`, it would return me `2` and `tea` would also return me `2`.

Anyone has an idea, how I can achieve this in a clean way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't apple return 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const input = [{name:"apple"},{name:"bone"},[{name:"banana"},{name:"tea"}]];

const myFind = (name) => input.findIndex(e => 
  Array.isArray(e) // check if element is array
    ? e.some(x => x.name === name) // if yes, check if contains name
    : e.name === name // if no, check if elements name is equal name 
)

console.log('bone:', myFind('bone'))
console.log('banana:', myFind('banana'))
console.log('tea:', myFind('tea'))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks! I will accept this as an answer as soon as I can.